# Resources under 'public' is not accessible from sub-domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, apache2, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.2 setup accessible from multiple sub-domains but using different database. i.e.

```
Domain : sample.com,      DB : sample-db
Domain : test.sample.com  DB : test-db
```

to change DB connection based on domain, I setup a middleware. Which is perfectly working.

Now, `sample.com` was previously setup and is working perfectly fine and able to access all resources under public directory. but `test.sample.com` is not able to access any resources from public directory.

**Problem:**

The issue is that I am getting 404 on a few assets from the public folder. All css and JS, but not all. The assets are in fact there which is accessible from main domain.

I'm running apache under Ubuntu env, getting error:

> 404 Not Found

**Apache Config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName sample.com
    ServerAlias www.sample.com test.sample.com

    ServerAdmin admin@sample.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sample/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sample-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sample-access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/sample/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are your views/controllers working fine? And it's just the public resources?

Comment: @Blakethepatton Yes. Views/controllers are working fine

Comment: Things I'd check are the permissions for the public folder are set up for your web user, I'd try restarting apache and I'd double check the vhosts.

Comment: @Blakethepatton all checked. Its working for 1st domain but not for 2nd. ```vhosts``` settings are same for both as I've added 2nd domain name as ```Alias```

Comment: Do you care to share the apache config you have set up?

Comment: @Blakethepatton shared.